# Don't want the single quotes in my python code

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-2.x

I am using Python 2.7... The problem I am facing is when i use this code

```
print "How old are you?",   
age = raw_input()  
print "How tall are you?",  
height = raw_input()  
print "How much do you weigh?",  
weight = raw_input()  

print "So, you're %r old, %r tall and %r heavy." % (
    age, height, weight)
```

The output comes to be -

```
How old are you? 35  
How tall are you? 6'2"  
How much do you weigh? 180lbs  
So, you're '35' old, '6\'2"' tall and '180lbs' heavy.
```

But I don't want the single quotes that come in the 4th line of the output around 35, 180 lbs ang 6 2".. how to do

Comment: Check out the common student questions: http://learnpythonthehardway.org/book/ex11.html#common-student-questions  Zed usually covers things like this and he certainly does for this one.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Dont use `%r`. Change:

```
print "So, you're %r old, %r tall and %r heavy." % ( age, height, weight)
```

To:

```
print "So, you're %s old, %s tall and %s heavy." % ( age, height, weight)
```

The difference between `repr()` and `str()` is that `repr()` is literal, and prints out the quotes with the string.

Here's an example in the interpreter:

```
>>> print '%r' % 'Hi'
'Hi'
>>> print '%s' % 'Hi'
Hi
>>>
```